# Translation by Non-Torsion Points on Smooth Genus 1 Complex Curves Does Not Arise from a Map of Graded Rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

This is Vakil 19.11 B, self-study.

Let $E$ be a smooth plane cubic in $\mathbb P^2_{\mathbb C}$. Then $E$ gives us a graded ring $S$. We know $E$ has a non-torsion point $p$. We wish to show that the map $t: E \to E$ given by translation by $p$ cannot come from a map of graded rings $S \to S$ even after regrading.

By putting the curve into Weierstrass form, we find

$$S = \mathbb C[x, y, z]/(zy^2 - x^3 - az^2x - bz^3)$$

We know any map of graded rings has to send $S_n \to S_{dn}$ for some fixed $d > 0$ and for all $n$. We know $t$ is an automorphism since it is a translation. I do not see how to connect all the pieces together to give the result. Strong hints are fine initially.

Comment: Do you see that d has to be 1?

Comment: I do not. Does this have something to do with the explicit addition operation? The main issue I am having is I do not have a good gauge on what it means for an addition of points to come from a map of graded rings. I have no real intuition for this.

Comment: It's just because it's an automorphism. Any automorphism has to have $d=1$.

Comment: Well, here's how I would think about it: If translation came from a map of graded rings, then the divisor $3(\infty)$ would be preserved (since it's O(1)), in other words, $3(\infty - p)$ would be trivial which is saying that p is 3 torsion under the equivalence between points and divisors on an elliptic curve. The regrading corresponds to replacing 3 by some other integer $n$.

Comment: Why is 3\infty the same as O(1)?

Comment: So we know that the pull back of O(1) in $\mathbb P^2$ to the elliptic curve is a divisor of degree 3 (this is what it means to be a cubic curve) and it's a theorem for elliptic curves that any 3 divisors on a line are equivalent to $3\infty$, this is a statement of the group addition law if you like.

Comment: Why is $3(\infty - p)$ trivial? Doesn't $3\infty$ map to $3(\infty + p)$ under translation? If that has to also be $3\infty$, how do we conclude?

Comment: $\infty$ maps to $p$ under translation, basically by definition ($\infty$ is the identity).

Comment: Of course! I was mixing up $p$ and $\infty$ in my head, as I am used to call $p$ the point at $\infty$ when dealing with elliptic curves. Thank you!